# Why can't I take the first row with this field from a datatable?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I want to take the field "size" from the first row and output it to the string openingRow. The query spits out nothing. What's wrong with it?

```
   string openingRow = (from row in MV.Data.AsEnumerable()
   select row["size"]).Take(1).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string openingRow = (from row in MV.Data.AsEnumerable()
   select row["size"]).FirstOrDefault().ToString();
```

Comment: Why can't I use Take(1)?

Comment: @Sean Take will return an IEnumerable and anyway it will not materialize the result in an object. What result do you get when you execute your query?

Comment: I get System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d_3a`1[System.Object] when I run my original query and the proper result when I run your's.

Comment: @Sean Ok, when you run your original query what you get is an IEnumerable of your object. Calling the ToString method on it will return something like a "description". Basically you are not materializing the result in a concrete object. To materialize it you can either call the ToList method or as I advised you call the FirstOrDefault method. I hope it's clearer